# Converting Java code with Bit operation from Java to JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, java, bit

I am re-writing a Java Code to Java Script and i got into this Bit operation that doesn't work the same,
here is the original Java Code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bos.reset();
short x = 451;
bos.write(x & 0xFF);
byte[] bytesArr = bos.toByteArray();
```

which gives me the one cell sized array: `[-61]`

this is the JavaScript Code:

```
var bos = [];
var x = 451;
bos.push(x & 0xFF);
```

this gives me the one cell sized array: `[195]`

I have a few more numbers besides the 451 and the transformation works fine for them, what am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried to make a GWT compile? It could help you, if there is a larger codebase.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript doesn't have fixed size integers, just a single number type, so you would have to use bitwise operators (which automatically treat it as a 32-bit integer) and sign-extend the 8-bits.

```js
var bos = [];
var x = 451;
bos.push(((451 & 0xFF) << 24) >> 24);

console.log(bos);
```

Or better-yet, use a typed array (you will need to know the size of your array first though).

```js
var bos = new Int8Array(1);
bos[0] = 451;

console.log(bos);
```